# Plural Possessive (With Mom and Dad's Love)

Tags: possessives, apostrophe, saxon-genitive, coordinating-conjunctions, compound-possessives

What is the best way to say "With Mom and Dad's Love"

1. With Mom and Dad's Love
2. With Mom's and Dad's Love

Option 1 sounds better, but I guess you could interpret that as Mom the person and Dad's love.

Comment: The second is correct. With Mom's love and with Dad's love. Or rephrase. With love from Mom and Dad.

Comment: Creating a bracelet and can only fit one more letter haha. Thank you.

Comment: This is not as simple as the examples in the 'duplicate'. Is the love considered as being individual (two apostrophes required, but 'love' is non-count) or as a single whatever (version (1)). Not as easy to decide as it would be with 'furniture'.